# Entity Data Model Wizard error (MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, devart

I am getting an error when trying to add postgres at the prompt asking what version of entity framework I would like to use I get the following error:

> Your project references the latest version of Entity Framework;
>   however, an Entity Framework 3 database provider compatible with this
>   version could not be found for your data connection. If you have
>   already installed a compatible provider, ensure you have rebuilt your
>   project before performing this action. Otherwise, exit this wizard,
>   install a compatible provider, and rebuild your project before
>   performing this action.

I have recreated the project and installed npgsql using the tutorial (https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/wiki/Visual-Studio-Design-Time-Support---DDEX-Provider#install-entityframework-6-npgsql-and-npgsqlentityframework-from-nuget) and I am still getting that same error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1Fzj.png)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do something like that:

Open Nuget:

1.Pre-install entityframework

2.Install Npgsql.entityframework

3. Rebuild your project.

Hope it helps;)